# How to load a video file into hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a sample video in  my localdisk(c drive).so I need to store it in hdfs.
please help me with the detailed procedure for it.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: You're looking for the `put` command. Here's the reference for it: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put

Comment: What is stopping you from using `hdfs dfs -put`

Comment: It is a video file with its extension .wmv.

Comment: Whatever, you can use `hdfs dfs -put`